# PhP's Mail Function Displays my CPanel Login Information

Tags: php, godaddy-api

I am sending an e-mail from my php code when certain events occur (i.e., someone posts a reply to a message on my message board). I used this simple code:

```
mail (me@aol.com, 'Someone Just Posted a Reply.', 'Check the message board, because someone just posted a reply.');
```

The code executes and I do receive an e-mail.  The problem is that when I get the e-mail, the "from" line in the e-mail gives away my cpanel login for my GoDaddy hosting account. I cannot seem to find anything on GoDaddy's site that explains how to disguise this or change this to just reflect the name of my website rather than give away my login to all users every time I send a push notification.

Comment: Without revealing any sensitive information can you describe what you mean when you say `the "from" line in the e-mail gives away my cpanel login for my GoDaddy hosting account`? You may be able to resolve this by adding some headers as a fourth argument to the [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, but that may possibly cause deliverability issues.

Comment: When someone posts, I receive an e-mail from the server, which is what is supposed to happen, but the "from" line in the e-mail says:  ###########@________.___.____.secureserver.net.  The redacted information I show as ########## is identical to my cpanel login that I use to host the site.  This is problematic from a security standpoint, but also from the perspective that when I send push notifications to people, I want them to know it is coming from my site and not some random server they've never heard of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the headers in the PHP's [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function's `additional_headers` parameters to add more stuff, but this may possibly cause deliverability issues.

> *This is typically used to add extra headers (From, Cc, and Bcc). Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (`\r\n`). If outside data are used to compose this header, the data should be sanitized so that no unwanted headers could be injected.*

With above being said, your updated code should look something like:

```php
<?php
  $headers = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',           // Add your from address.
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com',       // Add your reply to address.
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()          // Optional stuff.
  );
  mail(
    "me@aol.com",
    "Someone Just Posted a Reply.",
    "Check the message board, because someone just posted a reply.",
    $headers // This way
  );
```

**Note:** Make sure the above code is written in a single line.

Comment: Thanks Praveen.  I tried the above, but now I don't receive the email notification at all.  My guess is that there is some sort of "setting" on GoDaddy's website that I have to edit to somehow mask or provide an alias for the address from which the e-mail is being sent, but I cannot seem to find what it is.  I have to believe there is a fix to this, otherwise their Hosting service wouldn't be very useful.  In any event, thanks for trying.

Comment: @Rasputin Check your spam / bulk / junk email?

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out what I did wrong.  I used a different e-mail in the "from" than what GoDaddy assigned to me.  That was what was screwing me up.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yes, I just did.  Sorry.  I am new to this.